# can a single OAuth 2.0 Client IDs Credential work for different Domeins in other gsuite accounts?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-gsuite

We have Gsuite account where we created a OAuth 2.0 Client IDs (picture below) in order to implement our client application to users for Single sing on using (Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server). Is this ClienId sufficient to have in order for any private gmail domein to have access to our app thru sso? Is there a limitations of domains our app might have linked to this clientID? many of our clients have their own Gsuite account, but since we host the application, I imagine they don't have to create a clientID for every single gsuite account right? I tested and with different domain outside of our gsuite account and it works. I was just wondering what could go wrong in terms of limitations of domains or users?
Thanks guys appreciated.
[image]

Comment: if your using standard oauth2 and you only need one client which will identify your application to google.

Comment: So then i only need one clientid for any user any domein?  Of course as long as the client is always exists, correct ?

Comment: Your client id identifies your application to google you only need one client for your application,  it has nothing to do with the domain.